# Is it possible to call Razor @function from external javascript file?

Tags: javascript, razor

I am trying to resolve a CSRF issue within my WEB API. I am trying to implement the solution shown [here](http://dotnetthoughts.net/preventing-cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-attacks-in-webapi/).

From what I can tell, I need to create an @function{ ... } block in my Razor code, which I have done. (Basically the same function from the article)

```
@functions{
    public string TokenHeaderValue()
    {
        string cookieToken, formToken;
        AntiForgery.GetTokens(null, out cookieToken, out formToken);
        return cookieToken + ":" + formToken;
    }
}
```

I then have an external .js file that tries to call this method via the following:

```
 $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "POST",
    async: false,
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    headers: {
        'RequestVerificationToken': '@TokenHeaderValue()'
         },
    error: function (response) {
        alert(response.responseText);
    },
    success: function (response) {
        result = response;
    }
});
```

My "TokenHeaderValue()" method never gets called, furthermore I can see in Fiddler that the literal string of "RequestVerificationToken: @TokenHeaderValue()" is what gets passed, instead of the return result of "TokenHeaderValue()".

What is going on here? Why won't an actual call to the "TokenHeaderValue()" happen?

Comment: If your js is not in your razor view it won't work, @ tokens mean nothing in JavaScript. You could have an inline script in your view that you can call to return the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a global variable and reference this in your JavaScript it should work.

In your Razor view:

```
<script>window._csrfToken = '@TokenHeaderValue()';</script>
```

In your JS file:

```
$.ajax({
    //...
    headers: {
        'RequestVerificationToken': window._csrfToken
    },
    //...
});
```